# Differentiabilty of $f(x,y)=\sqrt[3]{\lvert x^2-(y+1)^2 \lvert}\sin(\lvert x+y+1 \lvert))$ at $(0,-1)$ , $(1,0)$ and $(-1,0)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, multivalued-functions

I want to show that this function is differentiable at these points. At $(0,-1)$ i use the definition to check the differentiability:
$\lim_{\substack{x\to 0 \\ y\to -1}} \frac{\sqrt[3]{\lvert x^2-(y+1)^2 \lvert}\sin(\lvert x+y+1 \lvert))}{\sqrt{x^2+(y+1)^2}}$.

I am not sure how to proceed.
Thanks for the help in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Hint at $(0,-1)$: Note $|x^2-(y+1)^2|\le x^2+(y+1)^2$ and $|\sin |x+y+1||\le |x+y+1|.$ So does

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,-1)} \frac{(x^2+(y+1)^2)^{1/3}|x+y+1|}{(x^2+(y+1)^2)^{1/2}}=0?$$

Comment: it should be $\sin |x+y+1||\le |x+y+1|$?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. If the limit I wrote down is $0,$ then $f$ is differentiable at $(0,-1).$

Comment: yes but i didn't understand how to check the differentiabilty at (0,-1). Ok we have to use the definition of differentiabilty but i didn't understand the next steps.

Comment: OK, let's back up a bit. Can you find the partial derivatives of $f$ at $(0,-1)?$

Comment: yes i can. i check this : 
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial x}f(0,-1)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h,-1)-f(0-1)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sqrt[3]{\lvert h^2\lvert}sin{\lvert h \lvert}}{h}=0$$
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial y}f(0,-1)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(0,h-1)-f(0-1)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sqrt[3]{\lvert -h^2\lvert}sin{\lvert h \lvert}}{h}=0$$

Comment: then to prove differentiability i need to check if the limit 
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,-1)}\frac{f(x,y)-f(0,-1)-f_x(0,-1)(x-0)-f_y(0,-1)(y+1)}{\sqrt{(x-0)^2+(y+1)^2}}$$ equals to zero. This limit becomes 

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,-1)}\frac{\sqrt[3]{\lvert x^2-(y+1)^2 \lvert}\sin(\lvert x+y+1 \lvert))}{\sqrt{x^2+(y+1)^2}}$$

Comment: That's right, and proving something $\to 0$ is the same as showing its absolute value $\to 0.$ And this leads to the estimates I mentioned.